# HttpURLConnection always return error 500

Tags: java, http

i'm trying to run a soap request in a basic http request...naturally i tried with external tools the message and is correct, like the endpoint i'm using as targetUrl, the wsdl is in something like

```
http://00.00.00.00/a-ws/services/basic?wsdl
```

and my actual end point is

```
http://00.00.00.00/a-ws/services/basic.targetservice
```

and i'm using this last as target url

```
          URL url = new URL(targetUrl);
          connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
          connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
          connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
          connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", action);
          connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "myagent");
          connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "localhost");
          //connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(message.getBytes().length));

          connection.setUseCaches (false);
          connection.setDoInput(true);
          connection.setDoOutput(true);

          //Send request
          OutputStream wr = connection.getOutputStream ();
          wr.write (message.getBytes());
          wr.flush ();
          wr.close ();

          //Get Response    
          InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
          BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
          String line=null;
          StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
          while( (line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
              if (line!=null)
                  response.append(line);
          }
          rd.close();
          return response.toString();
```

the raw message is tested with chrome plugin, the only thing i can't test is headers but the result is always an exception on getInputStream

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL:
```

why?

Comment: Error 500 is a response of your server, you should investigate why he send you this. Maybe it did not receive what it expects (data ?)

Comment: As already told if I try the same message from a browser plugin all works..it is a client problem, server just says that can't process the request for a generic reason, maybe encoding but I can't figure out where and how

Comment: For executing a SOAP command, try using a framework - e.g. http://cxf.apache.org/ - doing raw SOAP this way will rely on a lot of boilerplate code. We can't be sure why the server is giving an error. Perhaps you need to include the Accepts header?

Comment: It's just a suggestion - If you have an option to Use custom packages like Apache or Spring for HttpURLClient - use them.

Comment: It's an explicit decision to avoid dependencies, also axis doesn't seem so reliable! how can i get more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a very stupid issue of encoding (like I was supposing)...i didn't escape double quote inside the message.

The evidence of problem was visible using a fake http server that just echo contents.

UPDATE:
Another thing nobody already pointed out is that is useful in case of exception to retrieve

connection.getErrorStream()

that contains the response in case of error!